# How to install the PHP OAuth Extension on Amazon Linux

Tags: php, amazon-linux, oauth

In order to connect to QuickBooks from my PHP application, I need to install OAuth. I was following [these instructions](https://serverpilot.io/community/articles/how-to-install-the-php-oauth-extension.html) (substituting `yum` for `apt-get`) but after the first line

`sudo yum install gcc make autoconf libc-dev pkg-config` I see:

`No package libc-dev available.`
`No package pkg-config available.`

Are there Amazon Linux compatible equivalents for these packages? How should I proceed?

EDIT: After running `sudo yum install php-pecl-oauth` I see:

```
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Resolving Dependencies
—> Running transaction check
 > Package php-pecl-oauth.x86_64 0:1.2.2-3.3.amznl will be installed
—> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20090626-x86-64 for package: php-pecl-oaut
h-1.2.2-3.3.amznl.x86_64
—> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20090626-x86-64 for package: php-pecl
-oauth-1.2.2-3.3.amznl.x86_64
—> Running transaction check
 > Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.3.29-1.8.amznl will be installed
—> Processing Conflict: php56-common-5.6.14-1.119.amznl.x86_64 conflicts php-co
mmon < 5.5.22-1.98
—> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: php56-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.29-1.8.amznl.x86_64
You could try using —skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va —nofiles —nodigest
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those instructions aren't for Amazon Linux. You should not expect them to work.

And in any case, most yum-using distributions already have php-oauth packaged, so you don't need to do any of that. On Amazon Linux, the package name is `php-pecl-oauth`.

```
yum install php-pecl-oauth
```

And Bob's your uncle.

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work; see edited question.

Comment: You installed the php56- package set instead, so you should do php56-pecl-oauth.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! And where should I put the configuration file for the extension (next step in the instructions)? The directory `/etc/php5.X-sp/conf.d` doesn't exist.

Comment: You should not be reading those directions at all, nor doing anything mentioned in them. That configuration file is already installed from the package.

Comment: I still can't connect to QuickBooks so I'll have to figure out what else is wrong. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Did you restart PHP?

Comment: I restarted Apache, shouldn't that be sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

`php -m | grep -i oauth` - what does this say?

Also, depending on how you have configured Apache, I'd recommend creating a phpinfo.php file w/ the following content and check if the OAuth extension is actually enabled:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Comment: OAuth is loaded and working now, but thanks for the suggestion!